# Свое контекстное меню и всплывающая подсказка

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

Как на C# сделать свою всплывающую подсказку и контекстное меню? Хотя бы в общих чертах.

Comment: Forms или WPF?

Comment: Forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для контекстного меню есть стандартный компонент `ContextMenu`. На [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983580(v=VS.71).aspx) куча информации по нему. По ссылке выше найдете и примеры как динамически создавать контекстное меню. 
Для создания всплывающей подсказки также есть класс `ToolTip`. Можно от него наследоваться и переделать под свои нужды. Примеры:
[1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ballontooltip.aspx) [2](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4670&lngWId=10)

Comment: Про стандартные я знаю, интересует как раз наследование от них. Примеры сейчас посмотрю, спасибо
UPD: не совсем то что я искал, но можно вытащить намеки. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Для Forms

Это ToolTip.

```
// Создать контрол 
Button b = new Button();

// Создать подсказку
ToolTip t = new ToolTip();

// Задать значения
b.Text = "Кнопка"
t.ToolTipTitle = "Подсказка"
t.UseAnimation = true;
t.UseFading = true;
t.IsBalloon = true;
t.Active = true;
t.SetToolTip(b, "Что это?");
```

Это ContextMenu.

Для того контрола (например, TextBox - tb), который должен обрабатывать контекстное меню, выставить значение ContextMenu в cm

```
private void MyContextMenuEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MenuItem mi = new MenuItem("&Делать");

    if(cm.SourceControl == tb) {
       cm.MenuItems.Add(mi);
    }
}
```